# C++ why this code crashed while iterating and deleting from std::vector

Tags: c++, iteration

I was working on a leetcode problem to group anagram strings, the code below works, but it crashed if the line below was commented out, any one know why? It is related to iterating/deleting a std::vector. Thanks.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& strs) {

        vector<vector<string>> ans;

        while (strs.size() > 0)
        {
            string tmp1 = strs[0];

            vector<string> tmpAns{ tmp1 };
            strs.erase(strs.begin());          
            sort(tmp1.begin(), tmp1.end());

            auto itr = strs.begin();
            while (itr != strs.end())
            {
                string tmp2 = *itr;
                sort(tmp2.begin(), tmp2.end());

                if (tmp2 == tmp1)
                {
                    tmpAns.push_back(*itr);
                    strs.erase(itr);

                    if (strs.size() <= 0) break; // crashes at while loop if commented out
                }
                else
                {
                    ++itr;
                }
            }

            ans.push_back(tmpAns);
        }

        return ans;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    vector<string> in= vector<string>{"a", "a"};

    vector<vector<string>> ans = s.groupAnagrams(in);

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::vector::erase` invalidates iterators that reference anything at/after the deletion point, and also returns a new iterator. Check the [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) for an example of how to iterate and delete.

Comment: Also consider looking up [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), but note in the example the call to `erase` following the `remove_if`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above comment, the fix is inside the nested while loop:

```
if (tmp2 == tmp1)
{
    tmpAns.push_back(*itr);
    itr = strs.erase(itr);

}
```